# How to return the same name of a file with a little change?

Tags: r

I am doing some calculations for some files and then I am writing them back. my code here reads the data,does simple calculations, and then write the results and take the same name of the original file.

```
  dir1<- list.files("/data/fgoon", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
  for (files in seq_along(dir1)){
  hefile <- readBin(dir1[files], numeric(), size = 4, n = 1300*500, signed = T)
  results <- hefile+44.8                                                                                                                   
  outputDir  <- "/data/baie"
  outputFile <- file.path(outputDir, basename(dir1[files]))
  writeBin(as.double(results), outputFile, size = 4)
  }
```

The original file name is for example

```
  dert_E_lwe_20030102_yout.img
```

What I need is to return the same name (as done in the code) but change `lwe` to `sh` for all files:

```
   dert_E_sh_20030102_yout.img
```

all parts of the name are the same for all files except the date.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this (it's an idea):

```
str_replace_all(basename(dir1[files]),"lwe","sh")
```